# DatePicker in angular modal bootstrap

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup

Hi everyone guys i'm here again for ask some help from the community
i have to implement a datepicked in popup whit button on the right of the input of my modal but i don't know the right way for do this.
here the code of the modal

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica Paese</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="tableService.close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryName">Nome Paese</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryName" name="countryName" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryArea">Area</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryArea" name="countryArea" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.area">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryPopulation">Popolazione</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryPopulation" name="countryPopulation" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.population">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date">Data Censimento</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.date" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="tableService.close()">Chiudi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

this modal is in a component that is in another component and all function are in one service.
thanks for the help :)

i've tried some example whit ngx-bootstrap but i recive only a tons of errors.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/overlay/modal). Just replace the `bs-select2` with a `bs-datepicker`